# Webpack 5 sourcemap loaded by chrome in different "area" - unable to debug

Tags: reactjs, webpack, source-maps

I have two react components - I would like to be able to debug the jsx in chrome.

When I load the page I see my component code where I expect (using inline sourcemap)
[image: javascript code showing up where expected in chrome dev tools]

The sourcemap is loading (it works with a separate source-map file as well as in-line)
But it loads in another section under the "page" menu in chrome.
[image: source mapped jsx files show up under a section called "name"]

I see my jsx code as expected here. If I put a breakpoint (say on line 7 in the above picture) it will add the corresponding breakpoint in my minified code.  However if I "hit" the breakpoint it will hit in the minified code and not my original jsx (which I thought was possible with sourcemaps in chrome?)

I've used webpack for sourcemaps before - but I don't remember coming across this problem and haven't had any luck searching stackoverflow/google.

---

Here is my Webpack.Config

```
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

const SourceMapDevToolPlugin = require('webpack/lib/SourceMapDevToolPlugin');

const webpackEntries = {
  SavingsGoalAccount: './src/SavingsGoalAccount.jsx',
  SavingsGoalsList: './src/SavingsGoalsList.jsx',
};

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: webpackEntries,
  //devtool: "inline-source-map",
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',

    library: {
      type: 'umd',
      name: '[name]',
    },
    globalObject: 'this',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css)$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },

  externals: {
    react: {
      root: 'React',
      commonjs2: 'react',
      commonjs: 'react',
      amd: 'react',
    },
  },
  optimization: {
    moduleIds: 'deterministic',
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendors',
          chunks: 'all',
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin({
      cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: [path.join(__dirname, 'dist/**/*')],
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
  ],
};
```

It outputs in my dist folder as expected: [image]

Comment: Please post webpack config as well.

Comment: I added my webpack.config - thanks @RajKarri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `devTool` value as `source-map`. It will load the original code you wrote as source map. This also happened to me and I changed the devTool value to a different one as per my need.

As per webpack documetation - https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#devtool

if the quality is original then it'll load the entire code:
`quality: original- You will see the original code that you wrote, assuming all loaders support SourceMapping.`

If you don't need it. Please go with an option as per your need.